# Drupal 6 adding numbers to the end of a URL?

Tags: 6, uri

I have a problem that I originally thought was a leaflet.js issue, but i have now narrowed it down to drupal 6 adding numbers to the end of urls. I have seen many posts talking about addthis_config with drupal 7 but I have had no luck with that.

**Update:**
It is just the Y variable it is adding the extra value too if that helps anyone

Does anyone know where I can prevent the last `.86666870117188` from being added to my URL?
Some responses say to set this to false, though I didn't think i was using it.
`<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>`

```
http://xxxxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=RIVERFLIES_READONLY:sites_tbl,RIVERFLIES_READONLY:Blue-WingedOliveView1&QUERY_LAYERS=RIVERFLIES_READONLY:sites_tbl,RIVERFLIES_READONLY:Blue-WingedOliveView1&STYLES=&BBOX=-12.83203125,53.904338156274704,10.7666015625,60.973107109199404&FEATURE_COUNT=5&HEIGHT=600&WIDTH=1074&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&X=215&Y=101.86666870117188
```

**The code, i have removed the unnecessary stuff**

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.ie.css" />
 <![endif]-->
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script src="xxxx/drupal1/globals/leafletmaps/l.control.geosearch.js"></script>
    <script src="xxxxxx/drupal1/globals/leafletmaps/l.geosearch.provider.openstreetmap.js"></script>
      <script src="xxxxxx/drupal1/globals/leafletmaps/Leaflet.EdgeMarker.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet"xxxxxx/drupal1/globals/leafletmaps/l.geosearch.css" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function () { 
     var map = L.map('map').setView([55.07265,-1.000929], 6);
     L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map); 

  //Add second layer to map
     var riverflies_sites = L.tileLayer.wms("http://xxxxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/RIVERFLIES_READONLY/wms", 
    {
        layers: 'RIVERFLIES_READONLY:sites_tbl',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
    });
  map.addLayer(riverflies_sites);

    ////This created the layer control 
  var overlays={
   "Riverflies Sites": riverflies_sites}
   L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);

 //get feature info  add comma + the workspace:layer to display info for
 var popup = L.popup();
    function onMapClick(e) {
        var latlngStr = '(' + e.latlng.lat.toFixed(3) + ', ' + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(3) + ')';
        var BBOX = map.getBounds()._southWest.lng+","+map.getBounds()._southWest.lat+","+map.getBounds()._northEast.lng+","+map.getBounds()._northEast.lat;
        var WIDTH = map.getSize().x;
        var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;
        var X = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x;
        var Y = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y;
        var URL = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=RIVERFLIES_READONLY:sites_tbl&QUERY_LAYERS=RIVERFLIES_READONLY:sites_tbl&STYLES=&BBOX='+BBOX+'&FEATURE_COUNT=5&HEIGHT='+HEIGHT+'&WIDTH='+WIDTH+'&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&X='+X+'&Y='+Y;
        alert(URL);
        popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        popup.setContent("<iframe src='"+URL+"'  width='500' height='180' frameborder='0'><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>");

        map.openPopup(popup);
}
map.on('click', onMapClick); 

 };

 </script>
 </head>

  <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  </body></html>
```

Comment: Looks just like [this problem with addThis](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16283707/2389310) - do you have addThis installed? Does disabling it helps? What have you tried, exactly, and what was the effects of "no luck"?

Comment: Hi @Mołot I have not added addThis myself, and it doesn't show in the modules menu, This is pretty much a fresh install, the only modules different to the default enabled are a few custom forms, php filter, WYSIWYG text, and js injector.

Comment: OK, it means addThis solutions will not work. Now, PHP filted and WYSIWYG are out of the list too, pretty much. Are your custom forms modules altering links in any way? And what JS you are injecting? Is it operating on URLs? Without this data we will not be able to answer. Post relevant code, please.

Comment: sorry, the forms do not alter the URL's I will disable them and try. I will get the code now. Also the JS injector is injecting a dropdown menu, but thats limited to a specific page only

Comment: I am trying to think what ther details I can post. I have disabled all the modules I have created, and only left the default ones running. Another bit of info, the page is created using Leaflet.js which is a Java script library.  However that works fine outside of drupal. I also have Profile module enabled thats the only extra that is not set by default. @Mołot

Comment: How did you create page? Custom code that uses leaflet? Time to post your code (or close your question if you can't) - can't debug what we don't see.

Comment: @Mołot I have pasted the code, tried to cut the junk out of it. It is embedded within a page/node, that contains simple text.